# I can't understand why cordova link and Javascript coding is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Below is my cordova link which I've added in my HTML code but it's not working.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
```

I've added some Javascript below but I can't understand how to apply it.

```
$(function(){
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length}
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
     x[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
}
});
```

Can someone help me out please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are creating apache cordova app you should wait until device ready. Therefore  you have to use like this code block.

Index.js

```
(function () {
"use strict";

document.addEventListener( 'deviceready', onDeviceReady.bind( this ), false );

function onDeviceReady() {

 alert("I'm Ready!");

 //You can call  codes here
}
```

})();